# How to stop uploading .apk to BitBucket/ Github?

Tags: android, git, flutter, visual-studio-code, bitbucket

I am developing a flutter app, and recently build the .apk for android for testing. I am using BitBucket as the version control.

when I used `git push origin master` I noticed the .apk file also uploaded. This is not the best practice, so I do not want it. Now i have 2 questions.

1. Is it safe to manually visit the BitBucket and delete the .apk?
2. How can I stop uploading the android `app/release` folder? Here is my `.gitignore` file - https://pastebin.com/E6Cs0tdv (Paste Bin link as the formatting get messed-up with stackoverflow)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`.gitignore`** file

> gitignore file is a plain text file where each line contains a pattern
>   for files/directories to ignore.

```
# Built application files
*.apk
*.aar
*.ap_
*.aab
*.build
```

[image]

Comment: Ammend these to the bottom of the file? Also delete the .APK in BitBucket manually?

Comment: `Ammend these to the bottom of the file? - no matter . `Also delete the .APK in BitBucket manually?`  if you add this then your .apk will not push.

Comment: Thanks. ` **if you add this then your .apk will not push.**`  - I mean the one I accidentally uploaded to the git. Delete the `release` folder or `.apk` or not touch it at all?